# How can I make my base URL port number changeable for my requests pytests?

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest

So I have pytests (made using requests) and I run them while my server is running, to test if they work. They work fine but currently, the base URL is hardcoded to port number 3000 since my server is running on port 3000. How can I make sure these pytests run even if my port number is not hardcoded, i.e. if my server is running on port 4080 then the tests will succeed without me having to hardcode the URLs.

I tried doing this:

```
URL = f"http://127.0.0.1:{sys.argv[1]}/user"
```

since I take in the first argument as my port number when running my server. This does not work though. Any other suggestions for a beginner? Thanks

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=3000): Max retries exceeded with url: /user (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Comment: Could you share the error you get and the run command of your code?

Comment: @Gabip i edited my post to include the error. I simply run using pytest-3 user_test.py

Comment: Doesn't look like a problem in your code to me. Are you sure the server is running?

Comment: @shellysu are you that your server is up? Are you able to access it somehow?

Comment: @Robert yes the server is running and i made sure to 'import sys'

Comment: @Gabip yes the server is up and running and the tests work if i hardcode the port number

Comment: if you run `pytest-3 user_test.py` I understand why it doesn't work. You don't provide the port in the run command. Change it to `pytest-3 user_test.py 3000`

Comment: Check out the example in [Pass different values to a test function, depending on command line options](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#pass-different-values-to-a-test-function-depending-on-command-line-options).